# Calculate max value from Mon-Sun for every week

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table where I have to find the maximum weekly quantity for the data based on the date column in the past few years. In this example, say 06/07 is Monday and 06/12 is Sunday. Then in that week, the quantity 12 is the MAX value.

| Quantity | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-07 | 04:39:57.090 |
| 2 | 2022-06-07 | 04:39:58.850 |
| 3 | 2022-06-08 | 04:37:35.900 |
| 4 | 2022-06-08 | 04:37:37.247 |
| 5 | 2022-06-09 | 04:37:56.833 |
| 6 | 2022-06-09 | 04:37:58.190 |
| 7 | 2022-06-10 | 04:37:34.757 |
| 8 | 2022-06-10 | 04:37:36.103 |
| 9 | 2022-06-11 | 04:38:18.733 |
| 10 | 2022-06-11 | 04:38:20.100 |
| 11 | 2022-06-12 | 04:38:30.377 |
| 12 | 2022-06-12 | 04:38:31.833 |
| 13 | 2022-06-13 | 04:38:30.377 |
| 14 | 2022-06-14 | 04:38:31.833 |

I am trying to write a DAX script for this, but failing to do it because I am filtering on MAX date instead of value. Any help on how to modify this?

```
         CALCULATE(
            MAX( 'stock_xml'[Quantity] ),           
            FILTER( 'stock_xml',
                'stock_xml'[Date] = MAX( 'stock_xml'[Date] )
            )
        )
         RETURN 
            Stock
```

Comment: Image is not opening. Can you add your sample data and expected output from them in tabular format?

Comment: which  'value' do you want to filter?

Comment: @mkRabbani Edited the original to add example table. Offcourse in the real case there are 1000's of records of data starting from 2010.

Comment: If you are adding this as a column, try `CALCULATE(max('Table'[Quantity]),FILTER('Table',WEEKNUM('Table'[Date],2)=weeknum(earlier('Table'[Date]),2)))`, replacing `Table` with `stock_xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this below Measure script-

```
weekly_max = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('your_table_name'[Quantity]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('your_table_name'),
        WEEKNUM('your_table_name'[Date],1) = WEEKNUM(MAX('your_table_name'[Date]),1)
    )
)
```

Sample output-

[image]